# RAY MARCHING in BLENDER like this CODEPARADE video? With fractals, infinite loops, repeating infinite spheres...etc?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Hello I saw an amazing video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svLzmFuSBhk here with the spheres....the fractals....the infinite repeating planes....etc, is it possible to do something like this in blender? is it already in there somewhere? would it be possible to add it? anyone else dont anything like this? will it be added to blender soon if possible? Thank you all!

Comment: The short answer is yes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSQFt1Nruns , but it is a lot of math and there are lots of ways to do it.